# Trying to use nsIPrefBranch to store data on Firefox extension gives NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I'm trying to save a small amount of persistent data in a Firefox extension.

So, I'm trying to use `nsIPrefBranch` like this:

```
var db = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrefBranch);
if(db.getCharPref('epoch')){ ///do something.. }
```

but it doesn't seem to work and I'm getting this error:

> "Component returned failure code: 0x8000ffff (NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED)
>   [nsIPrefBranch.getCharPref]"

Can somebody please tell what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks Bob :) (for the spelling corrections..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no preference called "epoch" - that's what this message is telling you. You have to set this preference before you can expect `getCharPref()` to succeed. Which is why extensions usually wrap calls to `nsIPrefBranch` into `try .. catch` blocks - errors are expected.

On a different note: preferences are a shared space (have a look at them under `about:config`). You should make clear that a preference belongs to your extension and make sure it won't conflict with preferences of other extensions or the browser. In other words, use something like "extensions.myExtension.epoch" rather than "epoch".