# nsIPrefBranch for Firefox for android extension returns NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED

Tags: android, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, xpcom

I want to store a value in the preference of my extension (a firefox for android ext). So, in the prefs.js file (under defaults/preferences/) I write:

```
pref("extensions.trackdetect.idUser","nothing");
```

Then, in boostrap.js I get the preference branch:

```
var prefs = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1"]
                .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrefService).getBranch("extensions.trackdetect.");
```

But, when I try to get idUser value like this:

```
var idPref = prefs.getCharPref("idUser");
```

I get this error:`

```
Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x8000ffff (NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED) [nsIPrefBranch.getCharPref]"  nsresult: "0x8000ffff (NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED)"
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9120176/trying-to-use-nsiprefbranch-to-store-data-on-firefox-extension-gives-ns-error-un) explains the error origins, but my preference as I showed bellow  is set, so I don't understand the problem.

Comment: sorry the link of the post is : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9120176/trying-to-use-nsiprefbranch-to-store-data-on-firefox-extension-gives-ns-error-un

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrapped (restartless) add-ons do not support auto-prefs via `defaults/preferences`. It is the responsibility of your bootstrap code to set up default preferences accordingly.

Since your auto-prefs were never loaded, the `getCharPref()` call has to fail.

You will need to [get the default branch and seed your preferences](http://starkravingfinkle.org/blog/2011/01/restartless-add-ons-%E2%80%93-default-preferences/). An easy way to do so would be:

```
const PREF_BRANCH = "extensions.myaddon.";
const PREFS = {
  someIntPref: 1,
  someStringPref: "some text value"
};

function setDefaultPrefs() {
  let branch = Services.prefs.getDefaultBranch(PREF_BRANCH);
  for (let [key, val] in Iterator(PREFS)) {
    switch (typeof val) {
      case "boolean":
        branch.setBoolPref(key, val);
        break;
      case "number":
        branch.setIntPref(key, val);
        break;
      case "string":
        branch.setCharPref(key, val);
        break;
    }
  }
}

function startup(aData, aReason) {
  // Always set the default prefs as they disappear on restart
  setDefaultPrefs();
  ...
}
```

There are alternatives, like using [`mozISubscriptLoader`](https://github.com/nmaier/extsdk/blob/master/preferences.js#L138) or [Sandboxes](https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/blob/f29d2bb38c91d04e7733088308823c34fc390b6d/lib/sdk/addon/runner.js#L40), but I don't really have stand-alone code that can be easily copied for that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply nmaier, well in this case, based on Mark's article, the prefs will disappear once the session ends. However, i want it to be permanent. Besides, there is this extension ["Lock"](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/android/addon/lock/) that uses the auto-prefs and it works just fine, so I find this odd.

Comment: Only the default prefs disappear. If a user or code sets it to a non-default value, then the preference is indeed persisted. (Note the difference between `getBranch()` and `getDefaultBranch()` The code I posted is actually enough to make it work. Actually, the loader of non-bootstrapped extensions will do essentially the same thing as the above code with `defaults/preferences/*.js`. And the "Lock" add-on is broken in that regard. I added a link to the bugs in question to my answer.

Comment: Thanks Nils for the explanation, I tried your code and it works perfectly. Thanks again for your help.